# How to auto-create database tables from an array

Tags: php, mysql, database

Got very frustrated today trying to get this working.

I have about 20 tables that need to be created near the start of the my php script if they do not exist.

The obvious method would be the SQL query CREATE IF NOT EXIST however I don't want to query the database 20 times just to check if they exist or not, only when I want to create them.

I've tried looping through my table array then using SHOW ALL FROM database then comparing the table names, however that doesn't work (I have no clue why).

```
$result=$db->query("SHOW TABLES FROM database");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $numrows.' tables';

$found=null;

foreach ($table as $name => $fields) {
    while ($showall=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($name==$showall[0]) {
            unset($found);
        }
    }

            if (isset($found)) {
                echo 'Table '.$name.' does not exist, creating...<br />';

                $db->query("CREATE TABLE ".$name." (".$fields.")");
            } else {
                echo 'Table '.$name.' exists<br />';

                //$db->query("CREATE TABLE ".$name." (".$fields.")");
            }
```

That's my code so far (version 4, I reckon, after hours of trying to get it to work). As you can see, I loop within a loop and unset a variable if it finds a match. It sounds simple and it SHOULD work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are only declaring the $found variable twice and it is declared null both times. Because of that your code will never enter

```
if (isset($found)) {
                echo 'Table '.$name.' does not exist, creating...<br />';

                $db->query("CREATE TABLE ".$name." (".$fields.")");
            }
```

Maybe there is an issue?

Comment: True. But I've tried it with setting a variable to 1 and asking if that variable is set. This $found example I posted was a third of fourth attempt at getting it to work.